# Why the milliseconds are not working?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display in label9 a timer counting: Hours Minutes Seconds Milliseconds
Timer1 interval set to 1000

I'm calling this method from the timer1 tick event:

```
private void NewsUpdate()
        {
            newText = new List<string>();
            counter += 1;
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(counter);

            string time = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms",
                            t.Hours,
                            t.Minutes,
                            t.Seconds,
                            t.Milliseconds);
            progressBar1.Value = counter;
            label9.Text = time;
        }
```

I see the seconds moving counting but the milliseconds stay still on 000 why the milliseconds are not working ?

Comment: Because you are creating a `TimeSpan` from whole seconds? what would you expect the `Milliseconds` property to contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Interval of the timer to `1` and create `TimeSpan` object from milliseconds.

Update ur code as follows

```
timer1.Interval = 1;

private void NewsUpdate()
{
    counter += 1;
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(counter);

    string time = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D4}ms",
                  t.Hours,
                  t.Minutes,
                  t.Seconds,
                  t.Milliseconds);
    progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(counter / 1000);
    label9.Text = time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the timespan directly from the number of whole seconds.  Any timespan from an integer number of seconds will always have 0 milliseconds.

What you probably want is to either set your timespan to Date.Now(), or record the current time at timer start and subtract that from the current time on each timer tick.

Comment: Or even better, use `Stopwatch`